# Django admin forms error, delete form with errors and then press cancel

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am using Django 1.11.2.
In every form in admin(on edit), if I have errors on the form, and I press delete, and on the delete page I press cancel to go back, I receive this error:

`Confirm Form Resubmission
This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
ERR_CACHE_MISS`

If The form is clean and I don't have errors on it, is working.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is browser related : when you go back on a page where you submitted a form, the browser has the POST/GET values in its cache and asks you if you want to resubmit with the cached data.
You can only resubmit the data, you can't see the form as it was like that. You have to directly go to the URL (usually <kbd>F6</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)